# How to run octopus deploy on ecs cluster?

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, octopus-deploy

Is there anyone here that has deployed octopus deploy on Amazon ecs? On a Linux container preferably. I found docker image for octopus deploy but not sure what other components or customer parameters have to be set for it to deploy properly. Any help please? Thanks